# Следующее видео jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, видео

При отсутствии пользователя включается видео. При активности - выключается.
Воспроизводится первое видео, пользователь кликает и видео выключается, пользователь снова не активен и включается уже ВТОРОЕ видео. Если второе воспроизводилось, то включается ТРЕТЬЕ и так последовательно по кругу.
Как сделать такую последовательность?
Так же нужно сделать интервал между воспроизведением. Что бы первое, допустим, заканчивалось и проходило какое то время прежде чем включилось второе.
Спасибо.

```
<video id="video" autoplay="">
    <source class="vidActive" src="">
    <source src="">
    <source src="">
</video>
```

JS:

```
idleTimer = null;

$("#video").prop("muted", true);

$(document).bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    if(idleState == true){ 
         $(".video-container").css("display", "none");
         $("#video").prop("muted", true);
    }

    idleState = true;
    idleTimer = setTimeout(function() { 
        $(".video-container").css("display", "block");
        $("#video").prop("muted", false);
        idleState = true;
        return false;
    }, idleWait);
});
```

Comment: А потом если не активен пользователь? Снова первое, второе или какое-то третье?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если остановка произошла на 1ом видео, то активация второго видео, если на 2ом - то должно 3е воспроизвестись и так по кругу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задайте один источник видео для видео

```
<video id="video" autoplay="">
    <source class="vidActive" src="">
</video>
```

Берёте массив строк с `src` нужных видео. Также переменную `index`, которая будет хранить индекс.

```
idleTimer = null;

// к примеру, есть такой массив
var videoSources = [ "videos/vasya.mp4", "videos/kostya.mp4", "videos/petya.mp4" ];

var index = 0;

$("#video").prop("muted", true);

$(document).bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    if (idleState == true) {
         $(".video-container").css("display", "none");
         $("#video").prop("muted", true);
    }

    idleState = true;
    idleTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#video source").attr("src", videoSources[index]);
        $("#video")[0].load();

        index++;
        // Для проигрывания видео по кругу
        if (index == videoSources.length) index = 0;
        $(".video-container").css("display", "block");
        $("#video").prop("muted", false);
        idleState = true;
        return false;
    }, idleWait);
});
```

---

Для проигрывания видео по кругу нужна обработка для `$("#video")` события `ended`:

```
var idleState = true;

var idleTimer = null;

// к примеру, есть такой массив
var videoSources = [ "videos/vasya.mp4", "videos/kostya.mp4", "videos/petya.mp4" ];

var index = 0;

$("#video").prop("muted", true);

// вынесем в отдельную функцию проигрывание следующего видео
function playNextVideo() {
    $("#video source").attr("src", videoSources[index]);
    $("#video")[0].load();

    index++;
    // Для проигрывания видео по кругу
    if (index == videoSources.length) index = 0;
}

$(document).bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    if (idleState) {
         $(".video-container").css("display", "none");
         $("#video").prop("muted", true);
    }

    idleState = true;
    idleTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        playNextVideo();

        $(".video-container").css("display", "block");
        $("#video").prop("muted", false);
        idleState = true;
        return false;
    }, idleWait);
});

$("#video").bind("ended", function() {
    if (idleState) {
        // можете установить другой интервал
        setTimeout(playNextVideo, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно еще узнать, как сделать интервал между воспроизведением? Что бы первое, допустим, заканчивалось и проходило какое то время прежде чем включилось второе? Буду очень признателен

Comment: @Atomrr то есть когда первое заканчивалось, просто воспроизводилось второе? Когда пользователь ничего не делает, они должны дальше идти и по кругу?

Comment: Да да, именно так. И если активность пользователя так и не появилась - видео по кругу и между ними интервал в несколько секунд. Спасибо большое за ответ, очень помогаете

Comment: @Atomrr добавьте это в вопрос, а я сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: Добавил в конце

Comment: Извиняюсь, а есть ли тут интервал между воспроизведением файлов?

Comment: @Atomrr просто в обработке `ended` надо добавить `setTimeout`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, очень выручили! С наступающим! :)

Comment: Есть небольшая проблема, после проигрывания видео - не воспроизводится второе. Остается последний кадр предыдущего

Comment: @Atomrr Не совсем понял, Событие `ended` отрабатывает?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Залил несколько рандомных видео http://atomr-web.github.io/isuzu/

Comment: Извините, сейчас просто времени нет. Позже, когда вернусь, я посмотрю.

Comment: Хорошо, конечно. Буду ждать ответа. Через сколько примерно сможете ответить, можете сказать?

Comment: @Atomrr так надо было что-то добавить (сам код) в `function` для `$("#video").bind("ended", function () { // какой-то код })`;

Comment: Обновил код, тестируйте.

Comment: То, что нужно! Еще раз благодарю Вас!